# Why is the declaration of GridLayout different in Android Studio 3.5.1 compared to the earlier versions of Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

So I went through a tutorial today in which the creater used the earliest version of Android Studio 3.x.x and I found out that the line

`GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);`

would not work for my version of Android Studio (3.5.1).

After a quick google search I found out that I have to write

`androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);`

instead.

Can anyone explain why the code would get more complicated in the newer version and why the old code does not work? Also, why is the code for the declarations of other views still the same

(e.g. `Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);`) ?

Where does this inconsistency come from?

Comment: Because AndroidX is using instead of the appcompat support library in the example, for more info: [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: If you add an import statement for `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout` the old version should work as before.

Comment: ok, thanks to you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because they are using Androidx insted of Appcompat library. In order to migrate to AndroidX you have to change your dependencies in the Gradle as:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

So you can declare your GridLayout as:

```
androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```